# Calibration period

Tags: option-pricing, market-data, pricing, calibration, european-options

I want to calibrate some model to market data. This could fx be Bates, Kou, Black-Scholes, etc. So, for each model we have a set of parameters which need to be estimated through calibration. Now, my data set consists of many options with say 10 different maturities. For each maturity we have many options and therefore also many different strikes. So, my question is should I calibrate the model parameters for each maturity or should I calibrate one set of model parameters using all maturities.

References to papers are welcomed and also answers here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't quite given enough information.  The short answer is:  depends on the model and depends on what you're going to do with it.

Comment: The main goal is to calculate implied volatilities and compare them to the market implied volatilities. Regarding the model it should be applicable regardless. One thing is that the model is not path dependent. So, I'm not too concerned with which model, but rather what would be the correct approach. Either to do it maturity wise (we get 10 sets of model parameters) or do it for all maturities (we get one set of model parameters).

Comment: I'd say: Use European type observed option prices / IVs to calibrate parameters per-expiry and to **price** European type payoffs. Use prices of path-dependent products to calibrate a model which is used to then price path-dependent payoffs.